# django admin inline components

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I started learn django and I have question. Here is my models:

```
from django.db import models

class Color(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return '{0} ({1})'.format(self.title, self.code)

class Image(models.Model):
    color = models.ForeignKey(Color)
    src = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/img/')
    alt = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return '{0} ({1})'.format(self.alt, self.color.title)

class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

I need to have possibility to edit image instance on Manufacturer's page (manufacturer has one image). How can I do it in admin.py

I need something like:

```
class ImageInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Image

class ManufacturerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ImageInline]
```

But I receive

> Exception Value:
>
> <class 'catalog.models.Image'> has no ForeignKey to <class
>   'catalog.models.Manufacturer'>

I need one image for one Manufacturer

And second one:
I am planing to create product model, and one product can have many images. I think I should create many to many relation. So how can I describe Product in admin with many images?

Any ideas?

Comment: reverse your admin, or update your model. Put the foreign key in Image instead in Manufacturer

Comment: No, a lot of models has links to Image. e.g. Manufacturer, Product. Also customer can ask to have image for user. So every of these models should have key to Image model.

Comment: How can I reverse admin? Some images for Manufacturers, some images for products. When I edit manudacturer, I want to have possibility to edit image to/ When I edit Product - I want ability to edit few product images.

Comment: Your Manufacturer must be in the inline and your Image is the main

Comment: Cathy, no, I don't want to edit Image, I want to edit Manufacturer

Comment: Reverse your models then, it's up to you

Comment: Thats not correct. Other models can have Image. So they should have key to image model

Comment: Yeah I know what I mean is you cannot put Image in your inline unless Image has a foreign key of Manufacturer

Answer (score 0):

Exception message tells you everything. You need to add FK relation to Image model:

```
manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer)
```

If you need only one image for one manufacturer consider putting it in Manufacturer model. This would be more efficient (less DB queries or "select_related" functions) and easier to manage.

As for Many to many relation between Product and Image - just use ManyToManyField (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) in Product model and leave Image model as is.

Comment: I don't need foreign key in Image model. Because There is a lot of models, which have Image. Like Manufacturer, Product, User. So I don't need key for every one. I need receive image for manufacturer in admin by foreign key.

My Issue is about admin, not models